# gfortran and g77

Tags: 16.04, fortran

I'm compiling WRF on my personal machine to play around, I've done it successfully on another computer of mine. Then I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. This time I want to know why I'm doing what.

So in my previous installation notes I wrote to myself I should download gfortran and g77. Whats the difference? Is gfortran just the language and g77 a compiler and what's g95?

If anyone wants add why netcdf is such a struggle to download that would help to, it took me a couple of days to get it right.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g77` is the original GNU Fortran compiler - it is now deprecated in favor of `gfortran`. For a discussion of some of the differences and their implications see [Where has g77 gone to?](http://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/it-services/where-has-g77-gone-to)

`g95` is [The other GCC-based Fortran compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TheOtherGCCBasedFortranCompiler). It is maintained as an [independent project](http://g95.org/), outside of the GNU/GCC compiler collection. `gfortran` was originally forked from the `g95` codebase.